# how to add icons in row which is generated dynamically in ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

I am trying to make simple demo in ionic .I have one footer having one icon **ion-compose**(bottom left icon).When i click on that icon it show a pop up screen I enter name in text field and press **save** button .then it generate a row which have same text as written in textfield of popup screen.I need to add icon buttons on  row (like delete button , edit button).can we add icon on dynamically generated row as I did in footer (bottom left ion-composer).
Please add ion on row

here is my code

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qdEEPW

```
   <ion-item ng-repeat="item in items">
                {{item.testcase}}
                <ion-reorder-button class="ion-navicon"></ion-reorder-button>

            </ion-item>
```

please press bottom button on left side of footer .when click it show pop up snd fill entry it generate the row.I need to add icons on row

Answer (score 0):

you will have to be able to modify their framework to take a new key/value from the items object and pass it to the class that it gives the div.

```
res.class="icon-class";
$scope.items.push(res)
```

I modified your codepen to show you can pass the items object a class key/value
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbJJzO

Comment: please check this Question little bit more clear http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29861545/how-to-add-icon-on-row-in-ionic-framwork