# How to add icon on row in ionic framework?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

I am trying to make simple demo in ionic. I have one footer having one icon **ion-compose** (bottom left icon). When I click on that icon it show a pop up screen I enter name in text field and press **save** button. Then it generates a row which have same text as written in textfield of popup screen. I need to add icon buttons on row (like delete button, edit button). Can we add icon on dynamically generated row as I did in footer (bottom left ion-composer)?

Please add ion on row

Here is my code

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qdEEPW

```
   <ion-item ng-repeat="item in items">
                {{item.testcase}}
                <ion-reorder-button class="ion-navicon"></ion-reorder-button>

            </ion-item>
```

please press bottom button on left side of footer .when click it show pop up snd fill entry it generate the row.I need to add icons on row
 I will show the image what i want 
[image]
I need delete icon and edit button icon on row..you can choose amy icon from this link 
http://ionicons.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related: [how to add icons in row which is generated dynamically in ionic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29861053/how-to-add-icons-in-row-which-is-generated-dynamically-in-ionic/29861176?noredirect=1#comment47848806_29861176)

icons added.
You will have to add the functions for the buttons.

HTML:

```
    <ion-item ng-repeat="item in items">
        {{item.testcase}}
      <button class="button {{item.close}}"></button>
      <button class="button {{item.edit}}"></button>
```

JS:

```
myPopup.then(function(res) {
        console.log('Tapped!', res);
        if(typeof res!='undefined')
          res.edit="ion-edit";
          res.close="ion-close";
        $scope.items.push(res)

        console.log($scope.items);
    });
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbJJzO